# How can I turn a KFunction without instance param to a KFunction with it?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

```
class X {
    fun someFunc(x: Int, y: String, z: Double) {
        println("x = [$x], y = [$y], z = [$z]")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val func = X::someFunc
    val instance = X()

    func.call(instance, 1, "Hi", 123.45)
}
```

Given the code above how can I convert it to a function with instance built-in so when calling I can just pass the params without `instance`? <sub>(I could just use `X()::someFunc` but that's not the point of this question)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just implement a delegate wrapping that logic. Example implementation:

```
class KCallableWithInstance<out T>(private val func: KCallable<T>, private val instance: Any) : KCallable<T> by func {
    private val instanceParam = func.instanceParameter ?:
            func.extensionReceiverParameter ?:
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Given function must not have a instance already bound")

    init {
        val instanceParamType = instanceParam.type.jvmErasure
        if (!instance::class.isSubclassOf(instanceParamType))
            throw IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Provided instance (${instance::class.qualifiedName}) isn't an subclass of " +
                            "instance param's value's class (${instanceParamType::class.qualifiedName})")
    }

    override fun call(vararg args: Any?): T
            = func.call(instance, *args)


    override fun callBy(args: Map<KParameter, Any?>): T
            = func.callBy(args + (instanceParam to instance))

    override val parameters = func.parameters.filter { it != instanceParam }

}

fun <T> KCallable<T>.withInstance(instance: Any): KCallable<T>
        = KCallableWithInstance(this, instance)
```

And then use it like this (example based on the code in question): `func.withInstance(instance).call(1, "Hi", 123.45)`

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a `Pair` which maps the instance to the `KFunction`. Then you define an extension function `call` on that `Pair` like this:

```
// class X as defined in the question

fun <S: Any, T: Any> Pair<S, KFunction<T>>.call(vararg args: Any?): T {
    val (instance, func) = this
    return func.call(instance, *args)
}

fun main() {
    val func = X::someFunc
    val instance = X()

    val funcInstancePair = instance to func
    funcInstancePair.call(1, "Hi", 123.45)
}
```